# Getting ECL symbol name as string in C++

Tags: c++, common-lisp, ecl

I'm working on embedding Embeddable Common Lisp into a library and I've been writing utility functions to convert ECL's `cl_object` to various C/C++ types - e.g. to convert a `cl_object` representing a string to a std::string.

My question is this - why am I failing to retrieve a string containing the name of a symbol in ECL?

I'm having trouble getting the following function `ecl_symbol_to_string` to work, which should take an ECL symbol and return a std::string with it's name:

```
string ecl_symbol_to_string(cl_object sym) {
    return ecl_string_to_string(sym->symbol.name);
}

string ecl_string_to_string(cl_object echar) {
    string res("");
    int j = echar->string.dim; //get dimension   
    ecl_character* selv = echar->string.self; //get pointer   

    //do simple pointer addition
    for(int i=0;i<j;i++){
        res += (*(selv+i));
    }
    return res;
};
```

Note that `ecl_string_to_string` works for lisp strings.

A simple unit test illustrates the failure:

```
TEST_CASE( "ecl_symbol_to_string returns a string for symbol",
           "[ecl_string_to_string]" ) {

  LispRuntime *rt = new LispRuntime("()");
  std::string eval_script;
  cl_object   eval_result;
  std::string subject_result;

  eval_script = "'mysymbol";
  eval_result = rt->evaluate(eval_script);
  REQUIRE( ECL_SYMBOLP(eval_result) );
  subject_result = ecl_symbol_to_string(eval_result);
  REQUIRE ( ECL_STRINGP(cl_symbol_name(eval_result)) );
  std::cout << subject_result.c_str() << std::endl;
  REQUIRE( subject_result.compare("mysymbol") == 0 );

  delete rt;

}
```

This test case prints out `MM` for the call to cout. I have also tried comparing to "MYSYMBOL", which fails, and "M" which passes.

LispRuntime::eval_script simply converts and evaluates the form:

```
cl_object LispRuntime::evaluate(std::string &code) {
  cl_object form = c_string_to_object(code.c_str());
  cl_object result = cl_eval(form);

  return result;
}
```

I compiled ECL version 16.1.3 locally with the C++ option enabled, with debugging symbols and with all other settings default. Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe this is a unicode/non-unicode mix-up: ECL defines two string types in [object.h](https://github.com/ageneau/ecl-mirror/blob/master/src/h/object.h). One is `ecl_base_string`, where the member `self` ultimately typedefs to an `unsigned char*` and the other is `ecl_string` where the member `self` usually (depending on compile time arguments, I think) typedefs to a `int*`. You're accessing it as an `ecl_string`.

If you trace through the workings of `ecl_make_symbol` you find it ends up calling the function `make_constant_base_string` which returns a base string. Thus your `ecl_string_to_string` accesses it through the wrong type.

I suspect the easiest solution is to build a type-check/conversion into `ecl_string_to_string`:

```
string ecl_string_to_string(cl_object echar) {
    switch (ecl_t_of(echar)) {
    #ifdef ECL_UNICODE
      case t_string:
        if (!ecl_fits_in_base_string(echar)) {
          echar = cl_copy_seq(echar);
        } else {
          echar = si_copy_to_simple_base_string(echar);
        }
        break;
    #endif
      case t_base_string:
        // OK
        break;
      default:
        // PRINT SOME ERROR
        return string(); // or raise an exception
    }

    string res("");
    int j = echar->base_string.dim; //get dimension   
    ecl_base_char* selv = echar->base_string.self; //get pointer   

    //do simple pointer addition
    for(int i=0;i<j;i++){
        res += (*(selv+i));
    }
    return res;
};
```

The extra code I've added was heavily copied from the ECL function [`cl_make_symbol`](https://github.com/ageneau/ecl-mirror/blob/0476bca326ede723e883fe06c19c2cb748b1deec/src/c/symbol.d#L82). I decided to convert to `ecl_base_string` rather than `ecl_string` since the C++ string won't accept unicode characters anyway. You could probably do it the other way round if you had good reason to.

Comment: I'm afraid this is currently untested since I'm not in an easy position to test it right now, so it could be wrong (or more likely have minor errors in that you can hopefully fix!). Sorry if that is the case...

Comment: This does, in fact, solve the problem as written, and furthermore provides insight into the relevant internals so I'm able to research further on my own. Many thanks for this answer.